# Create variable or call method few times - What's better?

Tags: c#, variables, methods, garbage-collection

Im wondering about creating new variable or calling method few times.
What is better for overall performance and GC cleaning?
Take a look:

```
public static string GetValue(RegistryKey key, string value)
{
    if (key.GetValue(value) == null)
        return null;
    string newValue = key.GetValue(value).ToString();
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newValue))
        return null;
    return newValue.ToLower();
}
```

How can I make this code clear?

Comment: Most likely neither.  You can never tell what the compiler is going to do to optimize your code.

Comment: StackOverflow is about specific programming problems. If you want to talk about code quality, head for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Please check their How-to-Ask page before posting there (as you should have done here).

Comment: I guess, it's unnecessary premature optimization. On most cases  you should use profiler to find bottlenecks and optimize them.

Comment: This is not a case of premature optimization. If the `RegistryKey.GetValue` method does not cache its result, this call would require a registry access, which is several *orders of magnitude* slower than accessing a local variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, when you need to use the result of a method call multiple times, you should assign it to a local variable first. The local variable would only require your method's stack frame to be a few bytes larger (8 bytes for an object variable on 64-bit), and would get cleared automatically when the method returns – it has no effect on the GC.

The repeated method invocation, on the other hand, would require all its logic to be executed again, incurring the allocation of the required stack frames and possibly instantiation of objects. In your case, `RegistryKey.GetValue` makes the situation even worse, since it needs to access the Windows Registry, making it several orders of magnitude slower than the local variable access. Additionally, you could face race conditions where the two calls return different values.

```
public static string GetValue(RegistryKey key, string name)
{
    object value = key.GetValue(name);
    if (value == null)
        return null;
    string valueStr = value.ToString()
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(valueStr))
        return null;
    return valueStr.ToLower();
}
```

Note that this issue will be largely redressed in C# 6, where you can use the null-conditional operator:

```
public static string GetValue(RegistryKey key, string name)
{
    string value = key.GetValue(name)?.ToString();
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
        return null;
    return value.ToLower();
}
```

Comment: Wow, with C# 6 it will be a pice of cake! As I understand '?' will return null-string-value if its needed?

Comment: `a?.Foo()` will immediately evaluate to `null` if `a` is `null`. It will invoke (and return the result of) `a.Foo()` if `a` isn't `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Create a local variable and call the method once. There is (admittedly small) overhead to local method calls. If you were using a remote method call the difference would be much more pronounced.

Answer (score 0):

using ? operator makes it more readable
also better performance as u can see

```
public static string GetValue(RegistryKey key, string value)
{
    string valueStr=(string)key.GetValue(value);
    return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(valueStr)?null:valueStr.ToLower();
}
```

Comment: Why do you assume the ternary operator has better performance?

Comment: no. i mean better performance for directly casting to string...less if else comparing to OP code.i dont think using if else or ? affect performance that much.@YuvalItzchakov